# Composer autoload cannot find the class

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit, autoload, psr-4

I have a project with the following structure:

```
- src
  + Guitar.php
  + Type.php
  + ToString.php
- tests
  + GuitarTest.php
composer.json
```

And this is how I defined psr-4 autoload in composer.json:

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Shop\\Guitar\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Here is my Guitar.php:

```php
<?php

namespace Shop\Guitar;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Shop\Guitar\Type;

class Guitar
{
    public function __construct(public readonly string $serialNumber, public readonly Type $type)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is my ToString.php:

```php
<?php

namespace Shop\Guitar;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

interface ToString
{
    public function toString(): string;
}
```

Here is my Type.php:

```php
<?php

namespace Shop\Guitar;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

enum Type implements ToString
{
    case ACOUSTIC;
    case ELECTRIC;

    public function toString(): string
    {
        return match($this)
        {
            self::ACOUSTIC => 'Acoustic',
            self::ELECTRIC => 'Electric',
        };
    }
}
```

And here is my GuitarTest.php:

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Shop\Guitar\Guitar;
use Shop\Guitar\Type;

final class InventoryTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testGuitarConstructor(): void
    {
        $guitar = new Guitar('foo', Type::ELECTRIC);
    }
}
```

But when I run the test I get the following error:

```php
Error: Class "Shop\Guitar\Guitar" not found
```

What is the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is merely a question about the composer autoloader in the PSR-4 configuration.

- You composer.json configuration looks legit.
- The `require_once` calls do not. This is an autoloader, the class files must not require the autoloader.

If in doubt, put your autoloader configuration under test.

Next steps:

1. Remove those `require_once` calls, they will only distract you and prevent the trouble-shooting. Autoload configuration either works or not. If you distribute inclusion points over diverse files, this is more work to maintain and not at all necessary to do.
2. Re-organize your `tests` module to introduce an autoloader configuration test as you're having an issue with it:

   1. Move the contents from `tests`  into `tests/unit` to have a dedicated directory for your unit tests.
   2. Create the `tests/php`  subfolder and create an `autoloading.php`  file there-in. The folder is for PHP tests, that is you execute them with PHP directly (e.g. `php tests/php/autoloading.php`). The files content:

      ```php
      <?php

      namespace Shop\Guitar;

      require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

      ini_set('log_errors', '1');
      ini_set('display_errors', '0');
      ini_set('error_reporting', '-1');


      # Test Plan:
      # [1] interface autoloader test
      # [2] enum autoloader test
      # [3] class autoloader test


      $test = '[1] interface autoloader test';
      assert(interface_exists($name = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\ToString'), "$test: $name");

      $test = '[2] enum autoloader test';
      assert(enum_exists($name = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Type'), "$test: $name");

      $test = '[3] class autoloader test';
      assert(class_exists($name = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Guitar'), "$test: $name");
      ```

      References:

      - https://php.net/assert
      - https://php.net/interface_exists
      - https://php.net/enum_exists
      - https://php.net/class_exists
3. Run the autoloader configuration test, to check if the file could be loaded

   ```bash
   $ php tests/php/autoloading.php
   ```

(it must not print anything, it may however. Important is that it runs, not file-not found or similar kind of error.

If you're able to execute the PHP file this way, bind it in the composer configuration. This is so you can test your autoloader configuration.

Add a new script to your `composer.json` configuration:

```json
{
    "script": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@php -dzend.assertions=1 -dassert.exception=0 tests/php/autoloading.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

References:

- [Defining scripts - Composer Scripts Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#defining-scripts)
- [Command Events - Composer Scripts Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#command-events)

And test it:

```
$ composer run-script post-autoload-dump
> @php -dzend.assertions=1 -dassert.exception=0 tests/php/autoloading.php
PHP Warning:  assert(): [ ...
```

(it must not give output, here I put a bit of a warning in to show how it would look like)

This runs your new autoloading configuration test with assertions enabled in warning mode. That is you see errors if any of the ***_exists() functions returns false. That means that interface/enum/class could not be loaded.

You can make the test failing by changing `-dassert.exception=0` to `-dassert.exception=1` (`0` -> `1`). The test will then exit with a non-zero code (status `255` because of uncaught exception).

This is what you want, change `-dassert.exception=0` to `-dassert.exception=1` and save `composer.json` again.

Then you can test your autoloader with any composer command that dumps the autoloader:

- `composer dump-autoload`
- `composer install`
- `composer update`

Happy testing.

---

Apropos testing, perhaps check in the meantime if phpunit is still running:

```
$ composer exec phpunit -- tests/unit
PHPUnit ...
```

---

Apropos testing again, when you found the culprit and everything is in order again, you can run all tests with a single composer script.

Common is a script with the word `test`:

```json
{
    "script": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@php -dzend.assertions=1 -dassert.exception=0 tests/php/autoloading.php"
        ],
        "test": [
          "@composer dump-autoload",
          "@composer exec phpunit"
        ]
    }
}
```

And you don't need to write `composer run-script test` all the time, just `composer test` suffices:

```bash
$ composer test
Generating autoload files
Generated autoload files
> @php -dzend.assertions=1 -dassert.exception=1 tests/php/autoloading.php
PHPUnit ...
Time: 28 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

No tests executed!
```

(in this example output I have no phpunit tests configured yet, but you get the idea)

---

So what kind of tests are that? Well, I called it a configuration test, it is just a quick check where you can verify some PHP things. Don't add many of these tests and keep their Test-Plan small. You use it to address an issue you had configuring the project. Keep it up to a year and if you were the whole time error-free you can consider to remove it then.

The example shows however, how you can bring certain checks more near to the place of configuration and bind them together. Composer will make the overall process fail if there is a non-zero exit status.

Additionally you can add a description for each composer script, so that a message is shown:

```json
{
    "scripts-descriptions": {
        "test": "Runs all tests."
    }
}
```

```
$ composer list
...
  test                 Runs all tests.
...
```

(see: [Custom descriptions - Composer Scripts Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#custom-descriptions-))