# autoloading composer can't find class

Tags: php, composer-php

I was try on a beginners course php. I had a issue about autouploading with composer. I had Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'app\Email' not found in...

My directory structure looks like this

```
autoloading
    -app
        Email.php
        Person.php
    -src
    -composer.json
    -index.php
```

in index.php

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$email = new app\Email();
$person = new app\Person();
```

And in composer.json had

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Dung6\\Autoloading\\": "src/",
        "App\\": "app/"
        
    }
},
```

in `"App\\": "app/"` I was try ./app, /app/,... and I was composer dump-autoload every time I change. But nothing work at all. Some one can check it for me. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps just a character case issue: Uppercase `App`  the classname when you autoload them as well (`new App\....`). While class-names in PHP aren't case-sensitive in general, autoloaders are normally concerned about that because of case-sensitive file-systems and additionally class-maps that are case-sensitive. The beginners course perhaps is not very portable nor well reviewed. Please see in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/72621611/367456 answer how you can test your autoloader with composer (at the end).

Comment: And you didn't make the class definition visible in the question, therefore it is hard to say if that is exactly the reason.

Comment: Also, remember that PHP and the autoloading system don’t read the composer.json file, only the composer tool itself does. Depending on how your project is setup, you might need to run a [dump](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-) command